# Error: Index was outside the bounds of the array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, bellman-ford

I am writing BellmanFord algorithm in C#. However during run I am getting error:

`Index was outside the bounds of the array`

I don't know why it gives this error while array[6,6] = array that I initialized when reading the matrix.
This is my code:

> internal class BellmanFords
> {
> private int[] distances;
> private int numberofvertices;
> public static readonly int MAX_VALUE = 999;
> private int[] parent;
>
> ```
>         public BellmanFords(int numberofvertices)
>         {
>             this.numberofvertices = numberofvertices;
>             distances = new int[numberofvertices + 1];
>             parent = new int[numberofvertices + 1];
>         }
>
>         public void BellmanFordEvaluation(int[,] adjacencymatrix, int source)
>         {
>             for (int node = 0; node < numberofvertices; node++)
>             {
>                 distances[node] = MAX_VALUE;
>             }
>             Array.Fill(parent, -1);
>             distances[source] = 0;
>             for (int node = 0; node < numberofvertices - 1; node++)
>             {
>                 for (int sourcenode = 0; sourcenode < numberofvertices; sourcenode++)
>                 {
>                     for (int destinationnode = 0; destinationnode < numberofvertices; destinationnode++)
>                     {
>                         if (adjacencymatrix[sourcenode, destinationnode] != MAX_VALUE)
>                         {
>                             if (distances[destinationnode] > distances[sourcenode]
>                                     + adjacencymatrix[sourcenode, destinationnode])
>                             {
>                                 distances[destinationnode] = distances[sourcenode]
>                                     + adjacencymatrix[sourcenode, destinationnode];
>                                 parent[destinationnode] = sourcenode;
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>
>             for (int sourcenode = 0; sourcenode < numberofvertices; sourcenode++)
>             {
>                 for (int destinationnode = 0; destinationnode < numberofvertices; destinationnode++)
>                 {
>                     if (adjacencymatrix[sourcenode,destinationnode] != MAX_VALUE)
>                     {
>                         if (distances[destinationnode] > distances[sourcenode]
>                                + adjacencymatrix[sourcenode, destinationnode])
>                         {
>                             Console.Write("graph with negative circuit");
>                             return;
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>
>             for (int vertex = 0; vertex < numberofvertices; vertex++)
>             {
>                 if (vertex != source)
>                 {
>                     if (distances[vertex] == MAX_VALUE)
>                     {
>                         Console.Write("Trackless");
>                     }
>                     else
>                     {
>                         List<int> path = new List<int>();
>                         GetPath(parent, vertex, path);
>                         Console.Write("distance of source  " + source + " to "
>                                   + vertex + " is " + distances[vertex] + ". Its path is: " + path);
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>
>         public static void GetPath(int[] parent, int vertex, List<int> path)
>         {
>             if (vertex < 0)
>             {
>                 return;
>             }
>             GetPath(parent, parent[vertex], path);
>             path.Add(vertex);
>         }
>     }
> ```

And this is the input file:

> ```
> 6
> 0 6 0 7 0 0
> 0 0 5 8 -4 0
> 0 -2 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 -3 0 9 0
> 2 0 7 0 0 0
> 0 0 3 0 0 0
> ```

Please help me review it.
Thanks

Comment: Array indexing is 0 based.  So an array of size 3 can be indexed with 0, 1 and 2.  Your problem is lines like this `for (int sourcenode = 1; sourcenode <= soDinh; sourcenode++)` that should do less than, not less than or equals.  And should start at 0 not 1.

Comment: I'm not good at C# so I wrote in java first and it works fine. But when I convert to C# it gives error.

Comment: And on java side I am using starting index = 1 and using <= . condition. If fixed as you say, it doesn't work exactly what I want.

Comment: I'm not a Java dev by any means, but C# indexes are 0 based.  So if you wanted to iterate a simple 2D array it would be like this `for (int i = 0; i < someArray.Length; i++)`.  Start at 0 index and end one less than array length.  If `someArray` has a length of 6 then `someArray[6]` will fail - it's actually trying to access the *7th item* because the first item is 0 not 1.  That makes the 6th element `someArray[5]`.  I think your confusion stems entirely from 0 based indexes.

Comment: I see what you mean but if I apply my logic will be wrong while it is working fine on java side. It confuses me as to why the logic is wrong.

Comment: Java arrays are also zero based. You state that… _“And on java side I am using starting index = 1 and using <= . condition. If fixed as you say, it doesn't work exactly what I want.”_ … ? … it may not work as you want, but does it throw an index out of range exception? Either your java array is larger than you think or you will get an index out of range exception. Can you show the working java code that loops through the array as you describe?

Comment: it's exactly like C#'s loop. Because the syntax is similar.

Comment: It is unclear “why” there is any confusion… for both Java and C#... the array indexes are zero based. The error is very clear and the way the code is looping through the array only reenforces why you are getting an index out of range error. What is mysterious about this?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean but i fixed the index to 0 and it works. But the result is different between java and c#, can you help me why the same code on java and c# but 2 different results? I have updated my code.

Comment: Result in Java:

**distance of source  0 to 1 is 2. Its path is: [0, 3, 2, 1]

distance of source  0 to 2 is 4. Its path is: [0, 3, 2]

distance of source  0 to 3 is 7. Its path is: [0, 3]

distance of source  0 to 4 is -2. Its path is: [0, 3, 2, 1, 4]

Khong co duong di**

Result in C#:

**graph with negative circuit**

Comment: What part of a zero based indexed array and the structure of a typical loop through all its indexes are you not understanding? You claim that the Java code works by starting at index 1 and ending at the array size index and I am confident the only way this would work is if there was a minus 1 (-1) in the ending condition... otherwise an index out of range exception is guaranteed. Can you show this "working" Java loop as you describe?... In addition, how can we “compare” the Java code with the C# code if we do not see the Java code?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I forgot that array starts at position 0. Regarding the comparison between java and c# like I said it is 2 identical pieces of code, only differing in 2-dimensional array syntax. Let me find a way to share java files with you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YIY6oaUJAb0Fz1c6uJC7yWCNj5fgLu_4/view?usp=sharing